# How can I make a SQLite Database Context null in OnDestroy() in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have calling a SQLite database method in my Activity. I have given the following code `final DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(Lists.this);`to create an instance of the database in  my Activity.I have not given the above code inside OnCreate(). I want to make the context null on calling the OnDestroy method. I have done the following:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    System.gc();
    details.clear();
    DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(null);

}
```

Is It the correct way to make  the context null?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DatabaseHandler db=null;
```

instead of

```
DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

When your activity is destroyed, its member variables are also destroyed. No need to manually attempt to reset them.

Answer (score 1):

Just close Db

```
db.close();
```

it will destroy